# Regarding the different methodology of synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, executors

Please don't treat this below question as a duplicate one..!

I have developed a class that lets multi-threads to run sequentially, one at a time and in order.  All the application code between this class' claimAccess function and release Access function will be executed only in one thread at one time. All other threads will wait in the queue  until the previous thread completed. now Please advise can this same thing be achieved by some other means like executor, cycle barrier or countdown latch also..!!Please suggest how this can be build by other approach

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AccessGate {
    protected boolean shouldWait = false;
    protected final List waitThreadQueue = new ArrayList();

    /**
     * For a thread to determine if it should wait. It it is, the thread will
     * wait until notified.
     * 
     */
    public void claimAccess() {
        final Thread thread = getWaitThread();
        if (thread != null) {
            // let the thread wait untill notified
            synchronized (thread) {
                try {
                    thread.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * For a thread to determine if it should wait. It it is, the thread will be
     * put into the waitThreadQueue to wait.
     * 
     */
    private synchronized Thread getWaitThread() {
        Thread thread = null;
        if (shouldWait || !waitThreadQueue.isEmpty()) {
            thread = Thread.currentThread();
            waitThreadQueue.add(thread);
        }
        shouldWait = true;
        return thread;
    }

    /**
     * Release the thread in the first position of the waitThreadQueue.
     * 
     */
    public synchronized void releaseAccess() {
        if (waitThreadQueue.isEmpty()) {
            shouldWait = false;
        } else {
            shouldWait = true;
            // give the claimAccess function a little time to complete
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException exp) {
            }

            // release the waiting thread
            final Thread thread = (Thread) waitThreadQueue.remove(0);
            synchronized (thread) {
                thread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does ordering of tasks matter?

Comment: @NarendraPathai yeah have to maintain the order

Comment: What about `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`?

Answer (score 2):

This is by means of `ExecutorService`

[Executors.singleThreadExecutor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) will execute a single task at a time and will do it sequentially.

> Creates an `Executor` that uses a single worker thread operating off an
>   unbounded queue. (Note however that if this single thread terminates
>   due to a failure during execution prior to shutdown, a new one will
>   take its place if needed to execute subsequent tasks.) Tasks are
>   **guaranteed** to execute **sequentially**, and no more than **one** task will be
>   active at any given time.

Comment: could you please post the updated code as I have done that will help more to understand, Thanks

Comment: @user1881169 you should first try by yourself and then if there is some problem you can always ask again. :) We are here to help.

Comment: Thanks but I am unable to achieve that If you could please post the updated code it will be a great help,Thanks in advance

Comment: This would help http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html. If still you are not able to get post the updated code of yours and will help :)

Comment: I have gone through but could not understand completely , Please help me as I am stuck up,I have to convert the above approach through executors and I am stuck up completely,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are simpler ways to do this. The very simplest is just using a monitor, with no waiting, sleeping, or any other shenanigans:

```
// somewhere visible
public final Object accessGate = new Object();

// in your application code
synchronized (accessGate) {
    // this block will be executed only in one thread at one time
}
```

Java's built-in monitors provide pretty much the semantics you need. The only problem is that order in which threads get to hold the lock isn't guaranteed; that's down to how the underlying operating system handles ordering on locks (semaphores or mutexes or whatever). The operating system may well guarantee the behaviour you need, but this isn't generally portable.

If you need a portable guarantee of ordering, you have a few choices. The most obvious is a [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) with fairness set to true:

```
// somewhere visible
public final Lock accessGate = new ReentrantLock(true);

// in your application code
accessGate.lock();
try {
    // this block will be executed only in one thread at one time
}
finally {
    accessGate.unlock();
}
```

Another is a [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) with a single permit and fairness set to true:

```
// somewhere visible
public final Semaphore accessGate = new Semaphore(1, true);

// in your application code
accessGate.acquire();
try {
    // this block will be executed only in one thread at one time
}
finally {
    accessGate.release();
}
```

These two have very similar behaviour.

Comment: @TomAnderson..Thanks a lot , the two approaches that you have suggested are really helpful could you please post the complete updated code as I have done..that will help more to understand

Comment: Above code wont guarantee the ordering! But question mentions that ordering is to be maintained

Comment: @user1881169: No, i won't post the complete code. I have given you the information you need to solve this problem; it's now down to you as a programmer to make use of it.

Comment: @NarendraPathai: The approach using `synchronized` might not preserve the order, but the approaches using `ReentrantLock` and `Semaphore` do preserve the order, because they use them constructed with fairness. The javadocs i link to give more information.

Comment: @TomAnderson Please advise brother by posting the code as I have not understood and I am stuck upThanks

Comment: If you understand Java well enough to have written the code you posted in your question (which is quite complicated, but looks correct!), then honestly, it won't be a problem to understand these classes. Just read the javadocs i link to, and try some experiments.